# Eclipse Plugin: retrieve IProject from one of its files

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin, project

I am developing an Eclipse Plugin (Multipage Editor). The multipage editor consists in two pages: XML Editor + "Preferences" Editor. The Preferences Editor is just a way for the users to be able to define the XML file without knowing XML. For this, the plugin will show some text inputs, comboboxes, etc. To set the Comboboxes values (for instance), the plugin "scans" the project src classes (JavaProject), so the first combobox has the class names, the following have the attributes and the methods, from the selected class.
The issue is to scan the same project where the XML file is, without having selected the project before (not the way to do it in a development of a pop up menu).
An example:

[image: img]
In this test project the user will open the testFile.xml with the multipage editor. So, how can i have available the src hierarchy in my Preferences Editor page? In other words, how can I have the IProject instance of this specific project?

Update: Following the path that Bananeweizen has proposed, the issue would be getting the IFile object of the XML with which the editor is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that file as an `IFile` or `IResource`, simply call [`getProject`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html#getProject%28%29).

Comment: Obviously,  I do not have the IFile. I have the XML Editor + the "Preference" page that must do the scan before loading. Following this path the issue would be getting the IFile object of the XML with which the editor is working.

Comment: Your editor instance has an IEditorInput, which in your case should be a FileEditorInput, which you can ask for the related file.

Comment: @AegLos Obviously, you need to look at your editor's **init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)** method which should be called as the editor is starting up.  The IEditorInput should refer to the IFile, albeit indirectly.  There is a chance that the input is not an IFile, in which case your IProject lookup function wouldn't make sense or apply.